# Как использовать прокси?

Tags: c#, xnet

С помощью библиотеки xNet пробую считать html код сайта, используя при запросе прокси, скажите что я делаю не так?
код:

```
var proxyClient = HttpProxyClient.Parse("185.28.193.95:8080");
var tcpClient = proxyClient.CreateConnection("http://2ip.ru/", 80);
using (var request = new HttpRequest())
{
request.UserAgent = HttpHelper.ChromeUserAgent();

// Отправляем запрос.
HttpResponse response = request.Get("http://2ip.ru/");
// Принимаем тело сообщения в виде строки.
string content = response.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(content);
File.WriteAllText("asd.txt", content);

} 
Console.Read();
```

ip не меняется, что надо исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как то так. Писал в браузере но суть думаю понятна.

```
string ip[50];
ip[0]="185.28.193.95:8080";
ip[1]="121.28.193.95:8080";
string getContent(){
try{
WebClient web = new WebClient();
WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy(ip[index]);
web.Proxy = myproxy;
return  web.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
}
}catch(Exception ex)
{
index++;
 return getContent();
}
}
```

Comment: Лучше конечно циклопом делать чтобы ограничивать глубину рекурсии.

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать класс WebClient:

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("Proxy IP");
web.Proxy = myproxy;
String str = web.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
```

Все соединения будут устанавливаться через промежуточный адрес.

Comment: а как-то можно ли заменять автоматически прокси, на новый, если нынешний не рабочий?

Comment: Ну, прежде нужно будет где-то найти этот новый. Если использовать бесплатные прокси, то вероятность "угодить в молоко" гораздо выше. Поэтому придется либо вручную составлять список доступных прокси, либо покупать прокси со стабильным доступ

Comment: ну, мне сейчас просто для тренировки нужно заменить не рабочий прокси на рабочий, как мне осуществить замену? я буду прописывать исключение, и когда выскочит исключение, как мне скажем из файла или даже из другой переменной автоматически занести новый рабочий уже прокси и снова отправить запрос? мне просто пример нужен, потом где список рабочих прокси брать я сам  уже думаю разберусь)) нужен только пример

Comment: @inkorpus, catch на нужный тип exception'а, меняешь прокси и повторяешь запрос.